# Meaning of login_shell off

Tags: command-line, login

I have called the command `shopt login_shell`.  The result is `login_shell off`.  What does this result mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shopt` allows you to query or set shell options for `bash`. You can see how it's used by issuing `help shopt` (must use `help` since `shopt` is a bash built-in). You'll see that if you call it with an option name and no value, it'll just show the current value of that option. So it's telling you that the `login_shell` option is currently set to `off`.

What does `login_shell` mean? This explanation can be found in bash's man page (`man bash` and then search for `login_shell`). This means:

> The shell sets this option if it is started as  a  login
> shell  (see  INVOCATION  above).   The  value may not be
> changed.

So the result you get just means that this particular instance of bash is NOT a login shell.

You can learn more by reading the INVOCATION section of the bash man page, it goes into a ton of detail and is beyond the scope of your question :)

Comment: I thought that bash was used as a login shell in Ubuntu.  Is there some setup problem with my installation?

Comment: I thought my installation was using bash.  Does it matter what the login shell is?